# How can I copy lookup field value to another site list in lookup filed?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, javascript, visual-studio, jquery

How can I copy lookup field value to another site list in lookup filed?

Situation, I’ve a main site list , list1 and there have lookup field from list11, I've build sub site and copy my list1 from main site to sub site, but I can’t able to copy lookup field value to sub site list .
(In sub site I’ve a list same as list11 from main site.)
Have anybody have any trick  or advice  , I will be appreciate.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: How are you copying the lists. Are you creating the items programmatically or by a third party migration tool ?

Comment: Standard solution, through the saving as a template.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you save a list as a template, it will not preserve the lookup column as the IDs of the source column from which it looks up might change causing the lookups to break. There are a couple of workarounds which you can try. Try [this](http://sharepointknowledgebase.blogspot.co.uk/2012/09/retain-look-up-column-values-in-export.html?_sm_au_=iFVHWRPsq6W5016j) and [this](http://rehmangul.wordpress.com/2009/03/10/list-template-problem-with-look-up-columns/)